# how to combine overlay and camera image together in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, camera, overlay

I want to develop a application in which user can change there hair style. so i add a overlay in camera view by using following code files and try to combine both image.

Here is my `ViewController.h` file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate>{


    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
    UIPopoverController *popoverController;
    NSData *imageData;
}


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;


@end
```

and `ViewController.m` file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // assign action to button
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 60);
    myButton.center = self.view.center;
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [myButton setTitle:@"Image Picker" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.view addSubview:myButton];
}

- (void)buttonPress:(id)sender {
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        // alert the user that the camera can't be accessed
        UIAlertView *noCameraAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Camera" message:@"Unable to access the camera!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [noCameraAlert show];

    } else {

        // prepare imagePicker view
        imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];



        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        imagePicker.delegate = self;




        imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
        imagePicker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        imagePicker.toolbarHidden = YES;
        imagePicker.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;


        // create view for overlay
        CGRect overlayRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imagePicker.view.frame.size.width, imagePicker.view.frame.size.height-50);
        UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:overlayRect];

        // prepare the image to overlay
        UIImageView *overlayImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wig"]];
        overlayImage.center = overlayView.center;
        //overlayImage.alpha = 0.5;




        [overlayView addSubview:overlayImage];

        // add the image as the overlay
        [imagePicker setCameraOverlayView:overlayView];

        // display imagePicker
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

#pragma mark - UIBarButton Selectors

- (void)takePictureButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"takePictureButtonPressed...");
    // TODO: take picture!

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES
                     completion:^ {
                         [imagePicker takePicture];
                     }];

}

- (void)startStopButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"startStopButtonPressed...");
    // TODO: make this do something
}

- (void)timedButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"timedButtonPressed...");
    // TODO: implement timer before calling takePictureButtonPressed
}

- (void)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"cancelButtonPressed");
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - UIImagePickerController Delegate Methods

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {







    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated: YES];

    NSData *image1 =   UIImageJPEGRepresentation([editingInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage],1.0);



    UIImage *Imgg = [self addOverlayToBaseImage:[editingInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

    image1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(Imgg,1.0);
    imageData   =   image1;


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *imagePath =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",@"cached"]];

    NSLog((@"pre writing to file"));
    if (![imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:NO])
    {
        NSLog((@"Failed to cache image data to disk"));
    }
    else
    {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:imagePath forKey:@"imagePath"];
        NSLog(@"the cachedImagedPath is %@",imagePath);
    }


    [self.imageView setImage:Imgg];


}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (UIImage*)addOverlayToBaseImage:(UIImage*)baseImage{

    UIImage *overlayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wig.png"];
    CGPoint topCorner = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    CGRect scaledRect = CGRectZero;

    CGFloat scaledX = self.view.frame.size.height * baseImage.size.width / baseImage.size.height;
    CGFloat offsetX = (scaledX - self.view.frame.size.width) / -2;

    scaledRect.origin = CGPointMake(offsetX, 0.0);
    scaledRect.size.width  = scaledX;
    scaledRect.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);
    [baseImage drawInRect:scaledRect];
    [overlayImage drawAtPoint:topCorner];
    UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

    return result;  
}

@end
```

This code combine both image but i want the exact same image which user can see in camera preview. My problem is when i capture image and see image in UIImageview its totally different from camera preview.

**Camera Preview Image**

[image: Camera Preview Image]


 **What i get**

[image: What i get]

 Help me to get same image like Camera preview.

Comment: The image taken by the camera is of different resolution. You should resize the image to get the desired output.

Comment: can you explain me how can i get same resolution.

Comment: you need to use AVFoundation to get more control over the camera. Or if you dont want to use AVFoundation, you have to redraw the image on uiview based on your requiremnts by altering the image scale factor and the widht:height ratio.

Comment: You have to map your screen resolution on your camera resolution so actually you have to scale up your overlay image with respect to the camera resolution

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. I have fixed this issue here you can find my complete [git repo](https://github.com/milanitaliya/camera_overlay)

[Camera Preview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o1MP.png)
[What i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg2Oy.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).